# How to fix missing icons?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, icons

I have an issue with my Windows 7 where the small icons are missing from the address bar in windows explorer.

The icons are replaced with white squares.

[image: http://imgur.com/8HqUOFu]

Happened a few months ago, didn't bother me too much until now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be related to `icon-cache`; rebuilding may help. I've found some good links for icon-cache-rebuilding solutions:

Here are the steps to do it manually

1. Close and save anything that you are working on. This command will kill explorer and restart the computer when completed
2. Open a command prompt
3. In the command prompt, Copy and paste each command line below exactly as is one at a time and press enter after each command
   **WARNING**: The last command will restart the computer, so be sure to close and save anything that you are working on first.
4. Do the following:

   - ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache
   - taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
   - DEL "%localappdata%\IconCache.db" /A
   - shutdown /r /f /t 00
5. The IconCache.db file has now been rebuilt.
6. If the icons are still not displaying properly, then download and merge the ICO option in this tutorial for [Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html) or [Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8486-default-file-associations-restore-windows-8-a.html) to restore the default associations of .ico (icon) files.

[Microsoft Forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-missing-desktop-application-icons/c031fba8-3e05-4080-89b2-e8a89c460a6b)

[SevenForums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked a charm. Had previously contacted some guy at Microsoft Support and he wanted like $99 to fix it. What a joke!

Comment: For the purposes of anyone else trying to find the solution, the solution that worked for me was on the SevenForums website where it asked me to download a file called "Rebuild_Icon_Cache". I simply downloaded it and restarted my computer. The issue was solved afterwards.

Comment: glad it worked for you :)

Comment: @BorisSmith FYI, there's no need to restart Windows; logging off and back on is actually enough. As a side note, `ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache` only works in Windows 7 with IE 9 or later installed. Rather then killing `explorer.exe` in Windows Vista/7 you can open the Start menu, hold Ctrl+Shift, right-click an empty area, and finally select **Exit Explorer** from the context menu. In Windows 8.x you can get the same result by clicking the taskbar instead. This official article might also be of interest: [Icons change incorrectly in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2396571/en-us)